The logic of facts

The possibility of propositions is based upon the principle of the representation of objects by signs.
My fundamental thought is that the “logical constants” do not represent. That the logic of the facts cannot be represented.

L. Wittgenstein, TLP, 4.0312
I simply don't understand what logic of facts is. Is it just induction?

See 4.0311: names represent objects; predicates represent relations between objects. Logical constants (negation, etc) are NOT names of some sort of objects (because there are no "logical objects").

@MauroALLEGRANZA But there's no definition of logic of facts in your quote

He seems to be saying, we have things, but the relationships between them are not things. Ok. So?

i think he said that arithmetica is not same as physica
